# NoNode for /clusterstate.json : Lily + HBase + Zookeeper

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to index data from HBase via Lily, and I've faced with a problem:

```
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /clusterstate.json
```

I've manually added /clusterstate.json to zookeepers root, and there is an original file in /solr/ (on zookeeper), so I don't know what to to else with this problem.

Here is a bigger part of log:

```
2014-10-23 17:42:48,860 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.22.11:2181/solr,192.168.22.13:2181/solr sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@5d9329eb
2014-10-23 17:42:48,861 INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager: Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
2014-10-23 17:42:48,861 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.22.11:2181
2014-10-23 17:42:48,862 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hadoop1.mydomain/192.168.22.11:2181, initiating session
2014-10-23 17:42:48,864 ERROR org.lilyproject.indexer.batchbuild.IndexingMapper: Failure indexing record USER.100002222.type=friends
org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.SolrClientException: Error performing operation on Solr Solr Cloud Client
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.SolrClientImpl.add(SolrClientImpl.java:64)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:272)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:186)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:133)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:123)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.batchbuild.IndexingMapper$MappingTask.run(IndexingMapper.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZooKeeperException: 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.connect(CloudSolrServer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.request(CloudSolrServer.java:501)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
    at org.lilyproject.indexer.engine.SolrClientImpl.add(SolrClientImpl.java:62)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /clusterstate.json
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:637)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$10.execute(SolrZkClient.java:419)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:373)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:360)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:347)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.ensureExists(ZkCmdExecutor.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.ensureExists(ZkCmdExecutor.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.createClusterStateWatchersAndUpdate(ZkStateReader.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.connect(CloudSolrServer.java:242)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Moved solution from the question to a proper answer)</sup>

I don't know if something wrong with me, or with lily, but the problem was in zk path settings while collection creation - 192.168.1.1:2181,192.168.1.2:2181/solr instead of 192.168.1.1:2181/solr,192.168.1.2:2181/solr

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but the error is more in the sintax of zk asemble declaration, maybe your configuration in the solution have a little mistake, this configuration works for me :

"host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181/solr"

I hope that this response works for you